# Why I can not refer to table when join lateral function?

Tags: postgresql

I have query:

```sql
select * 
from dates d
left join (select * from range( d.start, d.stop ) ) x 
on d.start < d.stop
```

Which cause error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "d"
LINE 3: left join (select * from range( d.start, d.stop ) ) x on d.s...
                                        ^
HINT:  There is an entry for table "d", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Reading [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

> Table functions appearing in FROM can also be preceded by the key word LATERAL, but for functions the key word is optional; the function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM items in any case.

> A LATERAL item can appear at top level in the FROM list, or within a JOIN tree. In the latter case it can also refer to any items that are on the left-hand side of a JOIN that it is on the right-hand side of.

Inside `select * from range( d.start, d.stop )` the `range` is lateral.

Why I can not refer to `d` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a derived table you need the lateral keyword:

```
select * 
from dates d
  left join lateral (
    select * from range( d.start, d.stop ) 
  ) x on d.start < d.stop
```

If you remove the unnecessary derived table (aka "sub-query") the lateral keyword is optional (assuming your "range" function is a set returning function):

```
select * 
from dates d
  left join range( d.start, d.stop ) as x 
on d.start < d.stop
```

Comment: I need extra filtering, because bare `laterl join` does not work. It runs function when it should not (because condition is FALSE): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dfc2e8bcb5535e0856995f5933fded46

Comment: you have edited. cool, `lateral` before sub-query works well. I can accept answer in ten minutes